# How do I use python-magic to get the file type of a file over the Internet?

Tags: python, string, image, http, file

Usually I would download it to StringIO object, then run this:

```
m = magic.Magic()
m.from_buffer(thefile.read(1024))
```

But this time , I can't download the file, because the image might be 20 Megabytes. I want to use Python magic to find the file type **without downloading the entire file**.

If python-magic can't do it...is the next best way to observe the mime type in the headers? But how accurate is this??

I need  accuracy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call `read(1024)` without downloading the whole file:

```
thefile = urllib2.urlopen(someURL)
```

Then, just use your existing code.  `urlopen` returns a file-like object, so this works naturally.

Answer (score 2):

If it is one of the common image formats like png of jpg, and you see the server is a reliable one, then you can use the `'Content-Type'` header to give what you are looking for.

But this is not as reliable as using the portion of the file and passing it to python-magic, because if server had not identified the proper format and it might have set it to application/octet-stream. This is more common with video formats, but pictures, I think Content-Type is okay.

Sorry, I can't find any statistics or research on Content-Type's accuracy.  The suggested answer of downloading only part of the file is a good option too.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way with Python 3.

```
import requests
import magic
url = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png'
response = requests.get(url)
content_type = magic.from_buffer(response.content)
print(content_type)
```