# Identify uploaded file type from buffer

Tags: python, django

I'm using django to accept files from the user (mostly csv, text and excel). 
I need to detect the file type for further processing

Using [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) I'm getting different results for reading a file and a buffer

```
import magic

magic.from_file('/testfiles/xls.xls',mime=True)
'application/vnd.ms-excel'

f = open('/testfiles/xls.xls','r')

magic.from_buffer(f,mime=True)
*** TypeError: object of type 'file' has no len()

magic.from_buffer(f.read(2048),mime=True)
'application/octet-stream'

f = open('/testfiles/csv.csv','r')
magic.from_buffer(f.read(1024),mime=True)
'text/plain'

magic.from_file('/testfiles/csv.csv',mime=True)
'text/plain'
```

I got the idea for `f.read(1024)` from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677883/how-do-i-use-python-magic-to-get-the-file-type-of-a-file-over-the-internet)

I realize `octet-stream` indicate a specific application file type but I would like to verify it's excel.

*Note:* Django provides an attribute called [content_type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploadedfile-objects) for this type of thing but the documentation states that it relies on the file extension and should be verified.

**my question is**, What is the best way to identify the type of an uploaded file ?

Comment: Sorry but I do not see your problem. Could you put a `?` behind one of your sentences?

Comment: sure, edited the post with a more clear question...

Comment: which file types make sense? Do you need `.xls`, `.csv` or also `.doc` `.somefile`? csv is text and excel is octet if not further identified.

Comment: right now it's only excel/csv files. From what I understand every application specific file is of mime type `application/octet-stream`. I need to be able to differentiate doc from xls ... if i could get the first output `application/vnd.ms-excel` from the stream i would be happy.

Comment: This code worked for me on my test excel file (just made with Excel 2010 and saved as .xls format). `python-magic` is highly dependant upon libmagic, which is always changing. Perhaps, update to the latest libmagic and try again. Also, don't just read 2048 bytes. It's not always enough to tell the subtle difference between several excel variants. Read 1MB (1048576) bytes, which is more than enough for libmagic, and not really that much RAM usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filetype Python Package(pip install filetype). The below code worked for me :

```
import filetype

fileinfo = filetype.guess(mock.jpg) #the argument can be buffer or file
detectedExt = fileinfo.extension
detectedmime = fileinfo.mime
```

[filetype package documentation](https://pypi.org/project/filetype/)